# Null Pointer Exception in HashSets for Apriori

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashset, apriori

I'm designing an apriori program that needs to count the number of times a specific house attribute appears in a text file. The program needs to count how many times an attribute appears by itself, how many times the attributes appear in pairs and groups of 3+. I created a Subjects class that essentially connects the attributes. My goal was to read the file, use the subjects class to separate the attributes into specific categories, and create an ArrayList of these attributes. I then created a HashSet of the attributes(and the combinations of the attributes), using nested loops I will increase the counter of the attributes in the HashSet to determine the number of times they show up.

The problem is I'm getting a null pointer exception in my HashSet. I checked to make sure the object I'm adding to the set isn't null and its values aren't null but the exception is still there. Any suggestions? I'll post some code snippets below but please let me know if you need more.

```
//This is the loop giving me an error on the first iteration through:        
for (Subjects s: subjectListTwoElement){
    if(!s.equals(null)&&!s.identifier.equals(null)&&!s.partner.equals(null)){
        System.out.println(s.identifier+s.partner+s.count);
        subjectHolder.add(s);
    }
}
```

These are my variables and subjects class:

```
static ArrayList <Subjects> subjectList=new ArrayList();
static ArrayList <Subjects> subjectListTwoElement=new ArrayList();
static ArrayList <String> stringHolder=new ArrayList();

//keeps track of possible sets
static Set <String> ssv=new HashSet();

//possible values in next iteration
static Set <Subjects> subjectHolder=new HashSet();

static class Subjects {

    public String identifier="";
    public String partner="";
    public String partner2="";
    int count;

    public Subjects(String identifier, int count) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.count=count;
    }

    public Subjects(String identifier, String partner, int count) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.partner=partner;
        this.count=count;
    }

    public Subjects(String identifier, String partner, String partner2, int count) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.partner=partner;
        this.partner2=partner2;
        this.count=count;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
          return true;
        if (obj == null)
          return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
          return false;
        Subjects other = (Subjects) obj;
        if (identifier.equals(other.identifier)&&partner.equals(other.partner)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is my output:

```
Single Attributes:
Curb: 598
Paved: 6834
Asphalt: 11087
Curb & Gutter: 3483
Unknown: 4731

Double Attributes:
CurbAsphalt0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Code.printDouble(Code.java:178)
    at Code.main(Code.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the test `!s.identifier.equals(null)` into `s.identifier != null` and do the same for the test on `s.partner`.

`s.identifier.equals(null)` will give a NullPointerException if `s.identifier` is null since you are trying to call a method on that object.

Please let me know if this is useful.

-Kaj :)